# Include column with row number in multiple rows

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, wc

I want to include additional column count to multiple rows and the number to increase for example:

```
db1              CIRBS                            500           10
db2              CITEMP                           500           7
db5              IN_DATA                          500           6
dbb              IN_INDEX                         500           3
```

Final view:

```
1 db1              CIRBS                            500           10
2 db2              CITEMP                           500           7
3 db5              IN_DATA                          500           6
4 dbb              IN_INDEX                         500           3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{ print NR, $0 }' filename
```

`NR` is the number of the current record (i.e., line), `$0` is the whole line, so this will print an ascending number before each line.

Answer (score 5):

With cat:

```
cat -n infile
```

With nl:

```
nl -ba infile
```

With grep:

```
grep -n . infile
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed = infile | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

With GNU sed + xargs:

```
sed = infile | xargs -n2
```

With awk:

```
awk '{ print NR, $0 }' infile
```

Or:

```
awk '$0 = NR OFS $0'   infile
```

With perl:

```
perl -pne 's/^/$. /' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

In perl, you would use `$.` - current line number of current file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   # $. and $_ 
   print $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER . " " . $ARG;
}

__DATA__
db1              CIRBS                            500           10
db2              CITEMP                           500           7
db5              IN_DATA                          500           6
dbb              IN_INDEX                         500           3
```

For a simpler answer `cat -n` should do this too.

> ```
>   -n, --number
>       number all output lines
> ```

Comment: Why not `print "$. $_"`? What do you gain by splitting it out over two lines?

Comment: Not a lot. I just have an aversion to using `$_` if I can avoid it. (Although, given I'm using `$.` that's a bit of a moot point in this example).

Comment: But you are using `$_` in your code. You're just not using it explicitly. Surely that's worse? :-)

Comment: Personally - I'd say no. My _opinion_ is that any time you're actually using `$_` you should be writing your code differently to have an explicit named variable. Otherwise you continue the 'perl style' of looking like line noise. This has turned into a habit :). But using `$.` at the same time as eschewing `$_` is inconsistent, so I have amended it.

Comment: /me sees `use English` and shudders :-/